# How to prevent a file being copied or cut in windows file system?

Tags: windows, filesystems, copy-paste

I want that an exe file can't be copied or cut from the Windows file system to paste somewhere.

The exe is made in C#. which must have to be in only one PC.

I have worked with **FileSystemWatcher**, **NSIS**, **Clipboard**. but for all I need to detect whether that file is being copied.

I also have seen 'Prevent'(http www free-download-blog.com disable-cut-paste-copy-delete-rename-functions-using-prevent ), but I need to prevent only that particular **exe** from being copied or cut.

Any pointer or idea will help.

Comment: Hi,
i am not sure why you are doing this but isn't there alternative like writing in a registry the path from where for the first time the exe has started and checking against that registry or something like this ?

Comment: Here is one example but looks like there is no reg key like that :
http://techrepublic.com.com/5208-6230-0.html?forumID=49&threadID=51219&messageID=310118&tag=content;leftCol

I mean still ctrl+C is intact, I guess.

Comment: Set your exe to start at boot on a computer that have no usb, wi fi, cd drive, ethernet, floppy disk drive, external hdd drive? They ll be able to execute it, but hell if they find a way to access the system.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the exe to be executable, you need to permit loading it into memory.
As soon as you do, anyone can read it to memory using ReadFile and then write to an arbitrary location using WriteFile. No shell-detectable copying involved.

A good reading: [Raymond's post and its comments on preventing copying](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061206-00/?p=28813).

Comment: Exactly, if a user can read a file he can also copy it, period.
And even if he don't have privileges to read it, any sufficiently determined attacker will be able to circumvent any protection if he has local access or administrator rights.

Comment: Another way: One can also execute the program inside a debugger, and dump its process memory back to a file.

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested you won't be able to disable the copy/cut behaviour so easily.
An alternative would be to **disable the execution of the copied versions**. 
In your executable you could check many things like :

- The path of the present executable is explicitly your_path
- The name of the machine and user is the one you authorise

You could even prevent the file of being executed more than once using Windows register entries (if already 1 don't launch). It won't be perfect since any experimented user could tweak that out, assuming they are seeking for that. But depending on your users profile it might be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a hard problem. Even if you get explorer.exe to disable cut&paste, what prevents a user from using the command window? Or writing their own exe to do it? Booting up in linux and reading it?

Still, you have a few options (there will be more, most likely) which you could try:

- Use the right permissions: Set the
  permissions such that the users who
  you don't want to cut&paste cannot
  read the file.
- Write a device driver which can hook
  onto the filesystem calls and do that
  for you.
- Encrypt the file.

And some hacky options like:

- Use the APPINIT_DLLS regkey to put your own dll to be loaded into each process ( I am not sure if this will work with console process though). Then on your dll load, do IAT hooking to replace the kernel32.dll file calls.
- Replace kernel32.dll with your own version. Might have to do some messing around with the PE format etc.

There are no guarantees though. If for instance, you expect them to be able to execute it, but not copy it, you are probably stuck.

Comment: Execution should be allowed .. and not the copy/cut.
Booting up in linux and reading it is also a problem.
I am really stuck, But I still think there has to be a way.
For the time being I think I've to think for some other altenative than copy prevention stuff.
Thank for the quick reply. I'll be working on both the ways.

Comment: IMO the only suggestion you mentioned that has any remote feasibility is "Write a ... driver ...".  See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms793580.aspx -- of course, the ability to do something along these lines doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: If you can execute it, you can copy it, as others have mentioned. When you execute it it's already copied in memory. You'd have to be the OS to monitor the memory that safely and even then I could always run the whole thing on a virtual machine... you can't achieve copy prevention that way. James has a wise quote from Schneier.

Comment: Yes it looks so. Thanks. I was trying to prevent the applicatin from piracy, the other way.
I am to stop working further on it.

Comment: @Pessimist: Yes, I mentioned that if execution is required, they are stuck. @asveikau: You really cannot make a judgement call on this unless you have the questioner's context.

Comment: Also, can some please say why they gave this a -1? I can edit it to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Any local admin will be able to undo anything you do to prevent copying. I can pretty much guarantee the program on that page you mention relies on a service or background process to prevent copy-and-paste, and therefore is easily circumventable. If your users are in a closed environment where none of them are admins and they have very limited rights to their PCs, then you have a chance.

Comment: "Digital files cannot be made uncopyable, any more than water can be made not wet." --Bruce Schneier

Answer (score 0):

if you could completly block explorer from copying or moving files, then all u need is a 3rd party software for copying files (but make sure it can filter file extensions) for example Copy Handler

Answer (score 0):

Set up an ENVIRONMENT variable in your machine

In your code add a check 
if (ENVIRONMENT Variable=='Same as defined')
//Execute code
else
//Suspend execution